# If retornando sempre false no reduce()

Tags: javascript

Tô tentando fazer um simulacro de como seria um processo de autenticação com js puro (só pra dominar arrays), já consegui com outros métodos como filter, find, some, for, foeach etc. Porém com reduce, o if que faria a checagem dos dados retorna sempre false, independente do input do "usuário". Já tentei todos os statements possíveis todavia o resultado é sempre o mesmo

```
//função que seria chamada por um form
function auth() {       
    
    //inputs do usuário 
    var usernameInput = "a";
    var passwordInput = "a";

    //este seria o banco de dados
    const users = [
        {
            username: "a",
            password: "aa"
        },
        {
            username: "b",
            password: "bb"
        },
        {
            username: "c",
            password: "cc"
        }
    ];

    //hashmap pra percorrer o banco de dados 
    return users.reduce((msg, elemento) => {
        //ifs que retornariam uma mensagem para o usuário
        if (elemento.username == usernameInput && elemento.password == passwordInput) {
            return msg = 'log successful!';
        }
        //este sempre é o retorno :|
        else {
            return msg = 'wrong username or password';
        }
        if(!usernameInput || !passwordInput) {
            return msg = 'empty username or password';
        }
    },0);

}
```

Comment: O que voce gostaria que o reduce retornasse? Reduce é pra reduzir arrays a um único valor (por exemplo, numa arrays so de números, a soma desses números).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Não faz sentido usar `reduce` para isso

[Leia a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para entender o que `reduce` faz. Basicamente, ele recebe uma função, executa esta função para cada elemento do array e combina os resultados. A própria documentação [tem vários exemplos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Examples) de uso (por exemplo, para somar todos os números de um array, entre outros).

Mas você não quer combinar os resultados do processamento dos itens do array. O que você quer fazer é verificar se um dos elementos do array possui determinados dados. Nesse caso, não invente, use um `for`:

```js
function auth(users, username, password) {
    for (let user of users) { // faz um loop por todos os users
        if (user.username == username && user.password == password) {
            return true; // encontrei, retorna true
        }
    }
    // se chegou aqui é porque não encontrou ninguém, retorna false
    return false;
}

const users = [
    { username: "a", password: "aa" },
    { username: "b", password: "bb" },
    { username: "c", password: "cc" }
];

console.log(auth(users, 'a', 'a')); // false
console.log(auth(users, 'a', 'aa')); // true
```

Também mudei a função `auth` para receber como parâmetros o array de usuários, além do usuário e senha que devem ser procurados. Assim a função fica mais genérica, podendo ser reusada - essa é a ideia de funções, aliás, poder reaproveitar o mesmo algoritmo para parâmetros diferentes. Da forma que você fez, ela só funcionava para um grupo de usuários específico, mas fazendo da forma acima, você poderia usar outro array de usuários, por exemplo, que funcionaria sem problemas.

E fiz a função retornar somente `true` ou `false` (encontrou ou não o usuário/senha). Pois aí quem chamou a função que faça o que quiser com o resultado (podendo inclusive mostrar alguma mensagem). Acho melhor assim porque se a função retornasse a mensagem você ficaria muito dependente do texto específico, já retornando somente um *boolean* você pode mudar a mensagem à vontade:

```
if (auth(users, username, password)) {
    // autenticado: mostra uma mensagem qualquer
} else {
    // não autenticado: mostra outra mensagem
}

// *** As mensagens podem ser mudadas sem precisar mudar a função ***
```

Isso é melhor, porque se a função retornasse a própria mensagem, você teria que fazer algo como:

```
if (auth() == 'log sucessful!') {
    ...
}
```

E se um dia a mensagem mudasse, você teria que mudar todos os `if`'s que verificam o retorno da função.

---

No seu caso você quer uma mensagem específica caso os dados estejam em branco, então bastaria ter outro `if`:

```
if (!username || !password) {
    // mensagem dizendo que os dados estão em branco
} else if (auth(users, username, password)) {
    // autenticado: mostra uma mensagem qualquer
} else {
    // não autenticado: mostra outra mensagem
}
```

Pois se estiver em branco, nem valeria a pena chamar a função de autenticação - afinal, eu entendo que validar os dados (verificar se foram preenchidos) é uma ação diferente de autenticar (verificar se o usuário e senha batem), por isso eu deixaria isso fora da função `auth`.

---

Por fim, outra alternativa é usar [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), que verifica se algum dos elementos do array corresponde ao critério informado:

```
function auth(users, username, password) {
    return users.some(user => user.username == username && user.password == password);
}
```

E claro, o `for` mais tradicional:

```
function auth(users, username, password) {
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { // faz um loop por todos os users
        if (users[i].username == username && users[i].password == password) {
            return true; // encontrei, retorna true
        }
    }
    // se chegou aqui é porque não encontrou ninguém, retorna false
    return false;
}
```